# Verificar alterações numa table html

Tags: php, jquery, libcurl

Boa noite. Tenho uma tabela que pego via cURL.
Ela atualiza a cada 30 segundos, e exibe em um html. Essa tabela tem a situação de um personagem de um jogo (vivo ou morto).

Queria saber como faço para gerar um alert de cada linha da tabela que foi modificado (passou de vivo para morto, e vice versa).

**cURL:**

```
<?

$ch = curl_init("http://l2metal.com/?page=boss");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<table[^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}
echo '<table>';
    echo $matches[1];
echo '</table>';

?>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$.get('http://meusite.com.br/boss.php', function(data){
  $("#boss").html(data);
})
```

Isso exibe para mim uma tabela. Até ai está OK, mas eu queria uma luz do que posso fazer para exibir um alert quando algum monstro mudar de MORTO para VIVO. Estou perdido nessa parte.

Comment: Poste seu código e qual o problema que esta tendo, que os membros da comunidade irão te ajudar e responder seu problema com maior facilidade e rapidez,

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5484#5484

Comment: Desculpem, estava pelo celular ontem a noite. Código postado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a minha opiniao, é que teras que ler a tabela para dentro de alguma variável. Fazes um foreach por cada linha, e guardas o nome e o estado numa variavel global, quando les novamente comparas e fazes update a essa variável.

por variavel digo algum array de nome(key) e valor (estado do monstro)

ex:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="test">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          Jose
        </td>
          <td>
          Vivo
        </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          Andre
        </td>
          <td>
          Morto
        </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          Jose
        </td>
          <td>
          Vivo
        </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          Jose
        </td>
          <td>
          Vivo
        </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>

      var array ={"Jose":"Vivo", "Andre":"Vivo"};

       $("#test tr").each(function(index){
debugger;
         var key = $.trim($(this).find("td:first-child").text());
         var value = $.trim($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text());

         array[key] != value ? alert(key + " - ..") : "";
         array[key] = value;
                 });


</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Teria algum exemplo de como fazer isso: Pode ser uma pergunta respondida, link, qualquer coisa. Obrigado!

Comment: adicionei um exemplo.. agora o que tens que pensar é que precisas a primeira vez q entras na pagina tens q popular o array, por ex no documentready.. e a partir daí este código ja te vale.